# Custom token not displayed in Wallet

Tags: wallets

I'm following the first tutorial on Ethereum wallet. I have created a custom token (HelloWorldToken) based on the MyToken contract. The contract creation transaction has been validated but the tokens don't appear in my wallet. When I check the balance from the contract, everything seems fine. I can even transfer my tokens from my main account to my secondary account. But only using the contract transfer function.

How can I have my wallet display the custom token balance ?

I know you probably need some more info, but I don't know which ones. So apologies for the noobness.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38728/discussion-on-question-by-dora-esmephi-custom-token-not-displayed-in-wallet). If you want to update your question with more details, simply [edit](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/posts/3212/edit) it.

Comment: I'm on 0.9.0 and I need to add the token every time I restart the wallet. The custom token(s) don't get saved after I exit the wallet. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be due to [a bug in 0.7.1](https://github.com/ethereum/meteor-dapp-wallet/issues/149). Try upgrading to [0.7.2](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/0.7.2) and see if that fixes things for you. Otherwise you can try waiting for a fix to be released. Should be soon, judging by the comment from Van de Sande in the issue's comments.

Comment: Yep it fixed it for me!

Comment: I'm on 0.8.10 and have the same issue.